# How to find minimum frequency in an asynchronous design?

Tags: clock-speed

I want to know what all factors contribute in deciding minimum frequency of asynchronous domains.Also do mention the cases in which minimum frequency concept is required and why.

Comment: Unless your asynchronous circuit uses dynamic logic, which would be quite unusual, the minimum frequency is simply 0. Right?

Comment: My design is dynamic in nature.Two domains are there running on different clocks.I want to join both domains, so i want to alter both frequencies.So i wanted to the the minimum level upto which i can alter frequencies.

Comment: That would have been useful to say in the question. Also, is each domain synchronous within itself? Then you need to read and understand about "clock domain crossing". It's a huge problem and there's lots of info available. See also "synchronising asynchronous inputs" - normally you resynch the slower domain to the faster clock, inside the faster domain.

Comment: Sorry for the half information.My both domains are synchronous in themselves.I have done projects on CDC.But my main issue here is "minimum frequency".I have came across this term first time.I want to know when we need to see minimum frequency.From where it came.When we are required to calculate minimum frequency.I mean everything about "minimum frequency".

Comment: Or minimum frequency is just the relation between two frequencies needed to satisfy a particular CDC structure.If so, then is there any generalized way to calculate the relation between frequencies of two asynchronous domains which need to be synchronized.

Comment: My first comment still stands. Does either block have a minimum frequency below which it stops working?

Comment: No.It does not have that limitation.Is the minimum frequency relation with respect to each other?Like we say slow clock period should be 1.5 times fast clock period.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the minimum frequency of input changes which the output can properly handle. This is fairly simple. For each input, calculate the longest possible propagation time through the logic to the output. Find the largest of these delays. Then take the reciprocal of this worst-case delay, and that is the minimum frequency of the range of possible valid response frequencies.

If this is so, the possible sources of delay are fairly limited: device propagation and interconnect effects. Device propagation can depend on all sorts of factors, but the most common are device technology (CMOS, TTL, LSTTL, ECL, etc) power supply voltage and temperature. Interconnect factors can include connection length, line impedance, and input capacitance. In really pathological cases, asynchronous circuits can have unintended physical feedback paths which cause the output to oscillate, and thus never settle at all.

In general, specifying minimum operating frequencies for a logic circuit simply places a worst-case limit on expectations. It's no good trying for 100 MHz operation of a circuit which has a minimum frequency of 50 MHz. Since logic components typically have a range of response times due to process variations during manufacturing, a circuit with a minimum frequency of 50 MHz *might* work OK at 70 MHz (for instance), but that speed should not be expected.